How to properly add screen transition animations in jetpack compose?
I want to add transition animations while navigating from one screen to another in my app.
I have three screens in my app. When i navigate from the first screen to the second screen and also navigates back from it , then the animation is working fine. But when I try to navigate from the second screen to the third screen and then navigates back, the animation gets jumbled up.
composable(
                route = Screens.SEARCH_DETAILS_SCREEN.name + "/{name}" + "/{type}",
                arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument(name = "name") { type = NavType.StringType },
                    navArgument(name = "type") { type = NavType.StringType }
                ),
                enterTransition = {
                    slideInHorizontally(
                        initialOffsetX = {400},
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            600,
                            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                        )
                    )+ fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(600))
                },
                popExitTransition = {
                    slideOutHorizontally(
                        targetOffsetX = {400},
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            600,
                            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                        )
                    )+ fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(600))
                }
            ) 

I've used this for enter and popExit transition in the second and third screen composables. I believe the conflict is because of when i try to navigate back from the third screen, the enter transition of the second screen and the popExit of the third screen gets merged. I want to know the correct way to do it and how can i make it look good.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78017588/5513788

It's working fine but suppose if i have a lot of screens and i don't want this animation in some specific screens (like while navigating using the navBar) . So can i specifically remove this animation for those screens?

@CodePoet can you please tell me if it's possible to do so or not?

Sorry I don't know.
